# Having issues updating value in database in MVC5 Web Application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to learn MVC development and I am following a tutorial for creating a simple movie application located here - [Create a Movie Database Application in 15 Minutes with ASP.NET MVC (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/movie-database/create-a-movie-database-application-in-15-minutes-with-asp-net-mvc-cs)

Here are my Edit actions -

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var movieToEdit = (from m in _db.Movies
                           where m.Id == id
                           select m).First();
        return View(movieToEdit);
    }

    // POST: Home/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Movie movieToEdit)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add update logic here
            var originalMovie = (from m in _db.Movies
                                 where m.Id == movieToEdit.Id
                                 select m).First();

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View(originalMovie);
            //_db.Entry(movieToEdit).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            _db.Entry(movieToEdit).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

The guide calls for a line that states `_db.ApplyPropertyChanges(originalMovie.EntityKey.EntitySetName, movieToEdit);`, however it appears 'ApplyPropertyChanges' is obsolete. I tried using the line that is commented before I added a reference to the System.Data.Entity namespace.

When I run my app, I try to edit a field for one of the rows in the database, but nothing happens when I click the update button. I have a feeling it has something to do with that line that's now deprecated in the tutorial.

Comment: Try the newer tutorial for MVC 5. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

agreed you are **looking at a very old version ** (1 and 2) of MVC the current version is 5 or core.., the tutorial is very incomplete, they didn't even show how they assigned the 
values

This is how you could do it.... which is more inline with the correct version

```
public ActionResult Edit(Movie model) //renamed from movieToEdit
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var movie= _db.Movies.Where(m => m.Id == model.Id).SingleOrDefault();            
        movie.x = model.x;
        movie.y = model.y;
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(model);         
}
```